# Как сделать такую шапку?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Как сделать такую шапку? Использовать еще сетку (в моём примере *Zurb Foudation*) как на картинке.

Блок с логотипом не понимаю как растянуть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С остальными блоками разобрался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дайте идею, как быть.

Мой код:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-center-middle">


      <div class="site-branding cell medium-2">
        <?php
            the_custom_logo();
            if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) :
                ?>
          <h1 class="site-title">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
              <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
            </a>
          </h1>
          <?php
            else :
                ?>
            <p class="site-title">
              <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
              </a>
            </p>
            <?php
            endif;
            $astroi_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
            if ( $astroi_description || is_customize_preview() ) :
                ?>
              <p class="site-description">
                <?php echo $astroi_description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?>
              </p>
              <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
      <!-- .site-branding -->
      <div class="cell large-2">
        Пн-Пт 9:00 -18:00 <br> Сб, Вс - выхоной
      </div>
      <div class="cell large-3">
        companymail@gmail.com
      </div>
      <div class="cell large-3"><input type="search"></div>
      <div class="cell large-2">
        +7(831)272-75-24 <br> Заказать звонок!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'astroi' ); ?></button>
    <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
            ?>
  </nav>
  <!-- #site-navigation -->


</header>
<!-- #masthead -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно как-то так

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.logo-wrp {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px 20px 120px;
  position: relative;
}

.logo-wrp:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #000;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.logo {
text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.info {
  padding: 20px 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.navigation {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 70px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo-wrp">
    <a href="#" class="logo"><span>Логотип</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="cell large-2">
        Пн-Пт 9:00 -18:00 <br> Сб, Вс - выхоной
      </div>
      <div class="cell large-3">
        companymail@gmail.com
      </div>
      <div class="cell large-3"><input type="search"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      <a href="#">Текст меню 1</a>
      <a href="#">Текст меню 2</a>
      <a href="#">Текст меню 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```